# Appengine Serving Urls log

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

we're using Google Appengine image manipulation api (https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/) and serving urls to produce urls that our clients can use to display images.

Using this settings work great for our clients, but I am unable to find anywhere access logs to see who is accessing our content.

I have enabled the access logs  in the underlying Google Cloud Storage bucket, but I haven't seen any activity regarding the access of those objects.

Is there any way to setup/access those logs?

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no way to directly collect analytics from the image serving infrastructure that hosts and serves the 'http://lhx.ggpht.com' Image API transform URLs. This would be a good [feature request to file](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) for the Image API.

A workaround would be to take the returned serving URLs from the Image API and redirect to them from another service that does collect analytics such as the [Google URL Shortener](https://goo.gl/). With Google's URL Shortener you are able to append ['.info'](https://support.google.com/faqs/answer/190768?hl=en) at the end to see the analytics of a shortened URL.